# Getting an array result from json_decode

Tags: php, arrays, json

How do I get an array as a result from `json_decode()`?

I had an array like this:

```
$array = array(
  'mod_status' => 'yes',
  'mod_newsnum' => 5
);
```

and I saved this in database like JSON encode:

```
{"mod_status":"yes","mod_newsnum":5}
```

Now I want to get array again from database. But when i use:

```
$decode = json_decode($dbresult);
```

I get:

```
stdClass Object (
  [mod_status] => yes
  [mod_newsnum] => 5
)
```

Instead of an array. How can I get an array instead of an object?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I extract data from JSON with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29308898/how-do-i-extract-data-from-json-with-php)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Set the second parameter of [`json_decode`](http://php.net/json_decode) to true to force associative arrays:

```
$decode = json_decode($dbresult, true);
```

Comment: That should be the real answer. Much more helpful to me.

Answer (score 7):

As per https://www.php.net/json_decode:

```
$decode = json_decode($dbresult, TRUE);
```

Comment: +1 For using the abbreviation of “read the **fine** manual”. ;)

Comment: F is for freaking "F" word :P

Comment: oops! sorry, that comment was in a lighter vein :(

Answer (score 3):

```
$decode = json_decode($dbresult, true);
```

Or

```
$decode = (array)json_decode($dbresult);
```

Answer (score 1):

Casting the object result of `json_decode` to an array can have unexpected results (and cause headaches). Because of this, it is recommended to use `json_decode($json, true)` instead of `(array)json_decode($json)`. Here is an example:

Broken:

```
<?php

$json = '{"14":"29","15":"30"}';
$data = json_decode($json);
$data = (array)$data;

// Array ( [14] => 29 [15] => 30 )
print_r($data);

// Array ( [0] => 14 [1] => 15 )
print_r(array_keys($data));

// all of these fail
echo $data["14"];
echo $data[14];
echo $data['14'];

// this also fails
foreach(array_keys($data) as $key) {
    echo $data[$key];
}
```

Working:

```
<?php

$json = '{"14":"29","15":"30"}';
$data = json_decode($json, true);

// Array ( [14] => 29 [15] => 30 )
print_r($data);

// Array ( [0] => 14 [1] => 15 )
print_r(array_keys($data));

// all of these work
echo $data["14"];
echo $data[14];
echo $data['14'];

// this also works
foreach(array_keys($data) as $key) {
    echo $data[$key];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only use that data in PHP I recommend using [`serialize`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) and [`unserialize`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) instead or else you'll never be able to differentiate between objects and associative arrays, because the object class information is lost when encoding to JSON.

```
<?php
class myClass{// this information will be lost when JSON encoding //
    public function myMethod(){
        echo 'Hello there!';
    }
}
$x = array('a'=>1, 'b'=>2);
$y = new myClass;
$y->a = 1;
$y->b = 2;
echo json_encode($x), "\n", json_encode($y); // identical
echo "\n", serialize($x), "\n", serialize($y); // not identical
?>
```

[Run it.](http://codepad.org/BtpqedEY)

Comment: Doesn't answer question: should be comment instead.

Comment: @Mark It proposes an alternative that may be better. I consider those kind of answers valid as well. I added some more arguments in the latest edit.