# Handling $_POST array

Tags: php, mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Getting an array result from json_decode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5209330/getting-an-array-result-from-json-decode)
>   [JSON Decode in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5616880/json-decode-in-php)

I need help to store some selected $_POST data into mysql. I don't know variables names, it is instant notification function from cartloom like paypal ipn.

**ipn.php**

```
<?php
$data = print_r($_POST); 

$to = "hello065-65@yahoo.com";
$subject = "My subject";
$txt = $data;

mail($to,$subject,$txt,$headers);
?>
```

When i used `print_r($_POST);`

I received below content in my email..

```
order: {"billingFirstName":"sachin","billingLastName":"gupta","billingCompany":"df","billingAddress1":"33","billingAddress2":"","billingCity":"Chandigarh","billingState":"CT","billingPostalCode":"44444","billingCountry":"US","billingEmail":"hello065-65@yahoo.com","billingPhone":"","shippingFirstName":"","shippingLastName":"","shippingCompany":"","shippingAddress1":"","shippingAddress2":"","shippingCity":"","shippingState":null,"shippingPostalCode":null,"shippingCountry":null,"date":"Wed Apr 11 15:18:40 EDT 2012","transid":497070762,"invoice":1012,"grandTotal":"$0.00","payMethod":"none","comments":"","cartContents":[{"id":"48401","title":"Alex & Me - 10% Coupon","options":"","qty":"1","price":"0.00"}],"subTotal":"$0.00","discountAmount":"$0.00","discountTitle":"Complimentary Order","salesTaxTitle":"CT Sales Tax","salesTaxAmount":"$0.00","shippingTitle":null,"shippingAmount":"$0.00"}<br>
```

Can anyone help me, how to store **billingFirstName** **sachin** data into mysql..

Comment: Formatting your code and data sure makes a difference. We put effort into our answers for you, please put some effort into your questions for us.

Comment: Please have a look at the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) on how to ask a good question, and also maybe read this: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: Sorry guys, i am trying to store data posted via instant notification

Answer (score 2):

It looks like JSON to me

you could try..

```
$order_details = json_decode($_POST['order']);
$the_variable_you_want = $order_details['billingFirstName'];
```

Edit: Updated the example to more clearly show you how to get the variable you want.

Comment: Hi,  it is instant notification function from cartloom.

Comment: did you try the code I gave? Hopefully you can see what is happening with $order_details and take it from there.

Comment: yes i tried.. it is showing 1

Comment: I updated the code example hope it helps.

Comment: Your initial question was pretty loose to begin with, I thought I'd try and help anyway, your follow up statements have made me decide not to help any more.