# json parsing in php

Tags: php, python

I have the following JSON String

```
{
        "name":"Product",
        "properties":
        {
                "id":
                {
                        "type":"number",
                        "description":"Product identifier",
                        "required":true
                },
                "name":
                {
                        "type":"string",
                        "description":"Name of the product",
                        "required":true
                },
                "price":
                {
                        "type":"number",
                        "minimum":0,
                        "required":true
                },
                "tags":
                {
                        "type":"array",
                        "items":
                        {
                                "type":"string"
                        }
                },
                "stock":
                {
                        "type":"object",
                        "properties":
                        {
                                "warehouse":
                                {
                                        "type":"number"
                                },
                                "retail":
                                {
                                        "type":"number"
                                }
                        }
                }
        }
}
```

I would like to access

```
properties - > stock - > properties - > warehouse.
```

In python I can do the following.

```
f = open("c:/dir/jsondec.json")
data = json.load(f)
node = data['properties']['stock']['properties']['warehouse']
print str(node)
```

I'm trying to do the same thing in PHP. I know I can use `json_decode()` but what should be the correct syntax. 
Also If I have an array within say within `properties-> ID` I could have done `['properties'][0]['id']` to access that. What would be the equivalent in php?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5209330/getting-an-array-result-from-json-decode

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Version in Python

This is in Python:

```py
f = open("c:/dir/jsondec.json")
data = json.load(f)
node = data['properties']['stock']['properties']['warehouse']
print str(node)
```

### Version in PHP

And this is its equivalent in PHP:

```php
$f = file_get_contents('c:/dir/jsondec.json');
$data = json_decode($f, true);
$node = $data['properties']['stock']['properties']['warehouse'];
echo $node;
```

### "Gotchas" (or "slight differences")

There is one difference however: `f` in Python version is opened file, while `$f` in PHP version is already a string.

As RPM correctly noted, there is another difference: arrays in PHP are converted to string "`Array`" when used in string context (see here: http://ideone.com/XJfSP), so you probably would like to use:

```
print_r($node);
```

or

```
var_dump($node);
```

instead of

```
echo $node;
```

to see the actual content of the array.

**EDIT**: Changed `json_decode()` result into array.

Comment: `$node` is an associative array. Therefore, echoing node results in an array, you have to either echo `$node['type']` or `print_r($node)`

Comment: @RPM: Exactly, but it is the default way to convert array into string. Every array in string context will be displayed as `Array` as far as I remember.

Comment: Yeah for sure. I thought he would want to access the key / value from the warehosue array.

Comment: I am pretty sure that you need to update the json_decode($f) as json_decode($f, true), or use $data->properties-> bla bla ... instead

Comment: Yep, the output of json_decode without arguments is an object, not an assoc array

Comment: @LiangliangZheng: You are correct, I wanted that, but I forgot. Thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 0):

try using json_decode and casting the result as an object.

```
$r = file_get_contents('json.json');

$jsonObj = (json_decode($r));

$warehouseObj = $jsonObj->properties->stock->properties->warehouse->type;

d($warehouseObj);//to view warehouse node
d($jsonObj);// toview complete object

function d($l){
print "<pre>";
print_r($l);
print "</pre>";
}
```

Comment: The result is already an object, IIRC.  Assuming the JSON represents an object of course...and that you haven't said `json_decode($r, true)`.

Comment: actually there is no need to send $assoc= true because , you can parse the object retrieved by json_decode directly.

Answer (score 0):

In PHP, you can use [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) to turn an object into an associate array. Just make sure you pass `TRUE` as the second argument in the `json_decode` function.

```
   <?php
       $data = @file_get_contents('c:/xampp/htdocs/json.json');

      if(!$data)
      {
       echo "My bad";
      }
      $newData = json_decode($data,true);

      $a = $newData['properties']['stock']['properties']['warehouse'];

      print_r($a);
      echo $a['type'];

   ?>
```